# Add prefixes to CSS class names using LESS or SASS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less

I am trying to use Bootstrap on a project that encompasses 400+ sites and uses the previous CSS class names (which I have no control over). I've been running into some CSS name clashing and the solution for me is to add a prefix to Bootstrap (.row to .tb-row for example).

I am familiar with the method of adding a namespace using LESS, where an additional class is wrapped around the classes. Unfortunately, this doesn't look like it will solve my issues.

Is there a method via LESS, SASS, or any other compiler that makes it easy for me to add a tb- prefix to all existing classes in Bootstrap?

Comment: While I cannot speak for certain, I believe the answer is "no." Additionally, if you look at the bootstrap code, they use a lot of attribute selectors (so not just classes) to do things, some of which do and others do not depend on classes themselves as well. That adds to the complexity of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 18):

You could probably do this with SASS

- $namespace: "tb";
- `⌘ + f` (or similar) to find all the classes in your CSS file. You're going to probably need a regex (and some trial+error) to find them all.
- add `.#{$namespace}-` to all the classes.

Ideally, you'd get get something like this:

```
$namespace: "tb";

.#{$namespace}-myClass {
  background:pink !important;
}

.#{$namespace}-carousel-module {
  width: 25%;
}
```

compiled to

```
.tb-myClass {
  background:pink !important;
}

.tb-carousel-module {
  width: 25%;
}
```

"Easy" might be a stretch but "easier" seems fitting.

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, in honesty, I'm just [ripping off a gist that I saw](https://gist.github.com/chriseppstein/5649985) with comments from people a lot smarter than I am. May come in handy for you though!

Comment: I agree but it seems to be what the author is looking for

Answer (score 12):

You would need to modify the bootstrap code directly, an example of how this could be achieved elegantly in less:

```
.prefixname {
    &-row { 
        ...
    }  
}
```

Comment: i been trying to use this approach but for some reason is not working :(

Comment: If you have nested classes, with the prefix, a different solution might be better.

Answer (score 0):

I've added prefix "tb-" to all the bootstrap class (for LESS) in v3.1.0. So after you compile the less files you will get something like ".tb-btn"
You can fork my project at https://github.com/TimothyGuo/tb--prefix-for-Bootstrap-v3.1.0--LESS-

Comment: How did you build those files you have in your github repo. Thats exactly what i want to do.

Comment: I use git bash to push those files to my repository. You can either download the zip file directly from github, or pull down the repository to your local environment. I'm working on a project that need some prefix to bootstrap v3.1.0, but unfortunately I could not find anyone that already added the prefix to this new version. Therefore I decided to do it myself and share with the community. Hopefully this will help other developers.

Comment: thanks Tim, so how would this work with Bootstrap javascript components like modal, popover etc. which are building elements with specific classes and looking for elements with specific classes

Comment: The short answer is no. The JS will be a problem for now because the dependency on the original bootstrap class names. It's something that I need to work on later, and it will take me some time. I will update the repository as soon as I finished the prefix on those js files