# Adding third party application CSS to page without hurt to page CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I am building third party application with jQuery. My JavaScript and CSS files should be called into the page with `<script>` and `<link>` tags, respectively.

Recently, I have received some complains from other developers that my CSS has same classes as the main CSS file and it hurts the page main CSS. 
I resolved those problems with adding some prefixes to each of my classes.
e.g.

```
 .tooltip {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
        /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
    }
```

becomes:

```
  .mo-tooltip {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
        /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
    }
```

It was very time-consuming work and my question is this: Is there any less complicated solution for such a developer issues?

Comment: What sort of "3rd party application" you're talking about? If your markup (that presumably gets embedded into page) has a single container, you can use a unique `id` for it and write all of your css in that scope.. so `.tooptip` becomes `#your_unique_id .tooltip`. It is very quick if you're using a CSS preprocessor.

Comment: What tools for CSS preprocessing  exists? As U seen I do all work manually.

Comment: There are many but SASS (http://sass-lang.com/) is by far the most popular out there. Look into it, you will not be disappointed.

Comment: As @Ejaz mentioned, you should prefer using SASS. [Here is an example how to implement namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302333/add-prefixes-to-css-class-names-using-less-or-sass)