# Namespace Bootstrap4 CSS and JS Components

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Is there any way available as part of **Bootstrap4** `scss` based build to add prefix to each bootstrap class in `css` and `js` to avoid name collisions.

I have used https://github.com/faucamp/bootstrap_namespace_prefixer

But this only supports bootstrap3 based css and js files.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this for Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you make use of SCSS you can prefix the whole BS4 library like:

```
.myprefix {
  @import '~bootstrap.scss';
}
```

Prefixing the javascript is a little harder. I have not tried this but it looks like you can specify the `CONST` variables in each js file to match your prefix:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.5.0/js/src/button.js#L23-L25
After that create your own bootstrap index.js, define all variables there and import the classes you need. Or, create a plugin in your (webpack?) buildscript to dynamically replace all classes on build.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify the bootstrap code directly, an example of how this could be achieved elegantly in less:

```
.prefixname {
    &-row { 
        ...
    }  
}
```

credit for @raygerrard in this question [Add prefixes to CSS class names using LESS or SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302333)